# Java Apache HttpClient получает ошибку в ответ на запрос, который корректен в REST-клиенте Insomnia

Tags: java, http, rest

Я пишу клиент, загружающий файлы в хранилище по HTTP. Функция начала сборки файла из частей написана так:

```
public String startBuilding(String creator, String sysId, String name) {

        try (CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault()) {
            HttpPut request = new HttpPut(start);
            request.addHeader("creator", creator);
            request.addHeader("sysId", sysId);
            request.addHeader("name", name);

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
                System.out.println("File storage returned error");
                return null;
            }
            return response.getFirstHeader("fileTempId").getValue();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Она отправляет запрос на REST-эндпоинт с метаинформацией о файле, который надо создать. Однако в ответ на запрос возвращается ошибка.

Запрос: `PUT http://127.0.0.1:3000/commonfs/createWithBuilder/start HTTP/1.1`

Ответ `HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request: invalid header value [Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8, Connection: close] ResponseEntityProxy{[Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8,Chunked: false]}}`

Заголовки запроса:

creator: `FS-2`
sysId: `ARM-224016`
name: `Акт ГУ-23 №3 от 110918.txt`

Аналогичный запрос через REST-клиент Insomnia выполняется верно. В ответ приходит код 200. Что не так в джава-коде? Может, проблема в кириллице, которую инсомния незаметно кодирует?

Дополнение. Начал кодировать кириллицу:

```
 request.addHeader("name", URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8"));
```

В ответ все равно приходит `HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request [Date: Tue, 02 Oct 2018 13:15:44 GMT, Content-Length: 0] [Content-Length: 0,Chunked: false]}`

Comment: Просто догадка: Посмотрите значение заголовка `Content-Type`, которое  выставляет `Insomnia` и попробуйте выставить в коде такое-же.

Comment: @Oleg, попробовал выставить в Insomnia разные Content-Type (text/plain, application/json, application/octet-stream). С этими типами был всегда код ответа 200.

Comment: REST-сервер, которому из джава-кода отправляется запрос, возвращает 400, однако выполняет ту работу, которая требуется. Странно.